# Recyclerview issue with dynamic edittext

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview

- I am developing one app which dynamically adds rows inside `recyclerview` whenever **Add(+)** button is clicked as shown below:

[image]

- Whenever I delete first `edittext` without focus it works fine but when I have focus on first `edittext` and then I try to delete first item it hides `recyclerview` and when I hide/show keyboard `recyclerview` reappears.

DemoFragment.kt:

```
class DemoFragment : BaseFragment() {

    val TAG = DemoFragment::class.java.simpleName
    lateinit var binding: FragmentDynamicEditTextBinding
    var dynamicList = mutableListOf<MyModel>()
    lateinit var demoAdapter: DemoAdapter

    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
        binding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(inflater, R.layout.fragment_dynamic_edit_text, container, false)
        initViews()
        return binding.root
    }

    private fun initViews() {
        demoAdapter = DemoAdapter(dynamicList)
        binding.apply {
            rvHobbies.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(requireContext())
            rvHobbies.adapter = demoAdapter

            btnAdd.setOnClickListener {
                addValues()
            }
        }
    }

    fun addValues() {
        dynamicList.add(MyModel(0, ""))
        demoAdapter.notifyItemInserted(dynamicList.size - 1)
    }
}
```

DemoAdapter.kt:

```
class DemoAdapter(var items: MutableList<MyModel>) : RecyclerView.Adapter<DemoAdapter.DynamicViewHolder>() {

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int) = DynamicViewHolder(
        LayoutDynamicEdittextBinding.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(parent.context), parent, false),
    )

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: DynamicViewHolder, position: Int) {
        holder.bind(items[position])
    }

    override fun getItemCount() = items.size


    inner class DynamicViewHolder(var binding: LayoutDynamicEdittextBinding) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(binding.root) {

        fun bind(myModel: MyModel) {
            binding.apply {
                txtIndex.text = (layoutPosition + 1).toString()
                editValue.doAfterTextChanged {
                    it?.let {
                        items[layoutPosition].editData = it.toString()
                    }
                }
                imgCancel.setOnClickListener {
                    items.remove(myModel)
                    notifyItemRemoved(layoutPosition)
                    notifyItemRangeChanged(layoutPosition, items.size)
                    Toast.makeText(root.context, "Position: $layoutPosition items size: ${items.size}", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

layout_dynamic_edittext.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">


    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txt_index"
            style="@style/TextHealineStyle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="1"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/edit_value"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/edit_value" />

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
            android:id="@+id/edit_value"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginHorizontal="@dimen/margin_16"
            android:background="@drawable/rect_border"
            android:imeOptions="actionNext"
            android:inputType="text"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:padding="@dimen/padding_8"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textColorHint="#A6A8AB"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/img_cancel"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/txt_index"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/img_cancel"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/edit_value"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/edit_value"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_cancel" />

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</layout>
```

Comment: Try by removing this line `notifyItemRangeChanged(layoutPosition, items.size)`

Comment: But I want to maintain index position so whenver any edittext is deleted then sr. no is maintained.

Comment: Before removing/deleting clearFocus of edittext

Answer (score 1):

I got it working with this line in the adapter:

```
editValue.requestFocus()
```

Answer (score 0):

keyboard resizes the layout by default. In your manifest, use

android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"

for your activity.This would only resize the activity so as to the first focussable field that is your edit text is visible..for more information about possible values, read activity class documentation on official developer site.

Link : https://developer.android.com/training/keyboard-input/style